# Cliente consegue se conectar ao servidor mas crasha quando vai receber dados

Tags: c#, visual-studio, socket

Aqui vai a parte do código que da erro:

```
private void buttonAbrirConexão_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        socketOfServer = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socketOfServer.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 6554));
        socketOfServer.Listen(100);
        socketOfServer.BeginAccept(AcceptedConection_Callback, null);
        MessageBox.Show("Servidor aberto!");
        buttonAbrirConexão.Enabled = false;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        buttonAbrirConexão.Enabled = true;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void AcceptedConection_Callback(IAsyncResult e)
{
    socketOfClientOnServer = socketOfServer.EndAccept(e);
    socketOfServer.BeginReceive(bufferOfServer, 0, bufferOfServer.Length, SocketFlags.None, AcceptedDataFromClient_Callback, socketOfClientOnServer); //O erro da nessa linha
    MessageBox.Show("Cliente conectado!");
}
```

Antes de tudo eu sigo os seguintes passos, clico em abrir servidor, aparece uma mensagem dizendo que o servidor abriu, depois eu clico em conectar usando o ip 127.0.0.1, se eu remover a linha que está dando erro, me exibe uma mensagem dizendo que o cliente está conectado. O erro que está dando na linha é o seguinte:

"Uma solicitação de envio ou recebimento de dados não foi permitida porque o soquete não está conectado e (durante o envio em um soquete de datagrama usando-se uma chamada sendto) não foi fornecido um endereço"
Obs: Eu conecto apenas um cliente.

Comment: não conheço nada de .Net mas a linha que dá erro `socketOfServer.BeginReceive(bufferOfServer,...` deveria começar com `socketOfClientOnServer.BeginReceive(...`, porque "socketOfServer" é o listener, e "socketOfClientOnServer" é o socket conectado...

sobre os outros parâmetros não conheço o suficiente para dizer alguma coisa

Comment: Cara, você é no mínimo um semi-deus... ERA SÓ ISSO!!!! AAAAAAAA
O problema é minha falta de conhecimento sobre socket, então fui fazendo as coisas perdidamente :/
Agora é só avisar a minha família que não foi uma quimioterapia, eu arranquei os cabelos sozinho msm